# Parsing error in awk

Tags: shell, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing errors in awk blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201565/parsing-errors-in-awk-blocks)

I am getting a parsing error while executing an awk script. I am not sure abt this. Here is the script

```
`awk 'BEGIN 
{ 
INPUTFILE ='XXX'; iterator =0;
requestIterator =0;
storageFlag =T;
printFlag =F;
currentIteration =F;
recordCount =1;
   while (getline < "'"$INPUTFILE"'") 
   { 
         requestArray[requestIterator]++; 
         requestIterator++;
   }
 } 
 if ($1 ~ /RequestId/) 
 {  
        FS = "="; 
        if($2 in requestArray) 
        {
              storage[iterator] =$0;
              printFlag =T;
              next
        }
        else 
        {
              storageFlag =F;
              next
        }
  }
  else 
  {
       if((storageFlag =='T' && $0 != "EOE"))   
       {
            storage[iterator]=$0; iterator++;
       } 
       else {if(storageFlag == 'F')
       {
            next
       } 
       else
       {
           if(printFlag == 'T')
           {
                for(details in storage) 
           {
                print storage[details] >> FILE1;
                delete storage[details];
           } 
           printFlag =F;
           storageFlag =T;
           next
       }
 }
```

}
}' FILE2`

**Error**
zsh: parse error near `}'

Could you ppl please let me know whats wrong in this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parens are mismatched (13 x `{` vs 12 x `}`), so you are missing a final closing `}` at the end of your script.

I.e.,

```
next}}}}' FILE2
```

should be

```
next}}}}}' FILE2
```

Comment: Thank you..Now the parsing error has gone but there are two syntax errors EOE\)\){storage[iterator]=$0; iterator++;} else {if(storageFlag == F){next} else{if(printFlag == T){for(details in storage) { print storage[details] >> FILE1;delete storage[details];} printFlag =F;storageFlag =T;next}}}}}' FILE2

awk:  ^ syntax error
And also I am not sure why the additional \ are included...

Comment: @User Glad that solved your question for this particular problem . What you bring up now is I think a new problem and probably merits a different SO question. *However* I would strongly recommend you re-format the script to make it more readable, as it is it's quite gnarly and hard to read. It'll make it easier to help too. Also, I am not sure I understand your comment about "not sure why the additional \ are included".

Comment: ., Thank you.. Actually I am unable to format the code when I try to edit my question.. I am getting an error "You dont have much explanation on code".. I tried several times ... Could u pls help me

Comment: @User Chances are you'll probably find the latest error while you are reformatting your code .. that wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: I have finally formatted the code... Could you please have a look at the same

Comment: Post a new question, seriously.  Also, show some effort of your own.  If you remove parts of the script, it's easier to see any remaining error.