# Parsing errors in awk blocks

Tags: awk

```
awk 'BEGIN 
    { 
    INPUTFILE ='XXX'; iterator =0;
    requestIterator =0;
    storageFlag =T;
    printFlag =F;
    currentIteration =F;
    recordCount =1;
       while (getline < "'"$INPUTFILE"'") 
       { 
             requestArray[requestIterator]++; 
             requestIterator++;
       }
     } 
     if ($1 ~ /RequestId/) 
     {  
            FS = "="; 
            if($2 in requestArray) 
            {
                  storage[iterator] =$0;
                  printFlag =T;
                  next
            }
            else 
            {
                  storageFlag =F;
                  next
            }
      }
      else 
      {
           if((storageFlag =='T' && $0 != "EOE"))   
           {
                storage[iterator]=$0; iterator++;
           } 
           else {if(storageFlag == 'F')
           {
                next
           } 
           else
           {
               if(printFlag == 'T')
               {
                    for(details in storage) 
               {
                    print storage[details] >> FILE1;
                    delete storage[details];
               } 
               printFlag =F;
               storageFlag =T;
               next
           }
     }'
```

I am facing some syntax error in the above code. Could you ppl please help me?

awk: BEGIN{INPUTFILE =XXXX;iterator =0;requestIterator =0;storageFlag =T;printFlag =F;currentIteration =F;recordCount =1;while (getline < ""){requestArray[requestIterator]++;requestIterator++;}}if ($1 ~ /RequestId/){FS = "=";if($2 in requestArray){storage[iterator] =$0;printFlag =T;next}else{storageFlag =F;next}}else{if((storageFlag ==T && $0 != EOE)){storage[iterator]=$0;iterator++;}else{if(storageFlag == F){next}else{if(printFlag == T){for(details in storage){print storage[details] >> XXXX;delete storage[details];}printFlag = F;storageFlag =T;next}}}}

awk:                                                         ^ syntax error

awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^ syntax error

Comment: Your use of the variables `F` and `T` probably doesn't work like you would expect.  Use 0 for false and 1 for true instead, or define them explicitly in the `BEGIN` block.  Also note that `'T'` is not at all the same as an unquoted `T` (but `'T'` and `"T"` are equivalent in `awk`).

Comment: Also changing the value of `FS` mid-script is probably not going to do what you expect.  You need to reset it back to its original value when you're done with the `RequestId` handling.

Comment: You are defining `INPUTFILE` but never using it, and interpolating a shell variable with the same name instead (which I'm guessing is undefined).  Why do you want the value in a variable if you only use it once, anyway?  Just use `getline<"XXX"` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have cleared all the errors and the only error I am getting now is a syntax error .. i am not sure why

Comment: Am I supposed to use a statement like this if((storageFlag =='T' && $0 != "EOE"))

Comment: Yes, that's right.  All strings have to be quoted.  As indicated elsewhere, it's probably simplest if you use double quotes throughout.  For what it's worth, unquoted identifiers will be interpreted as variable names (which default to a value of zero if uninitialized), which of course isn't a syntax error, but certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are the problem. The first single quotes on `INPUTFILE ='XXX'` is going to be parsed as matching the one before BEGIN, and from then on all the parsing is broken.

Either escape the quotes or just put the awk file into a seperate file rather than "inline".

```
# STARTING POINT - known bad
awk 'BEGIN { INPUTFILE ='XXX'; iterator =0; ... '
```

Has to be rewritten to remove all of the single quotes inside the outer pair

```
 awk 'BEGIN { INPUTFILE ="XXX"; iterator =0; ... '
```

Or depending on if you need doubles or singles, use doubles outside and single inside

```
awk "BEGIN { INPUTFILE ='XXX'; iterator =0; ... '
```

or escape the singles quotes so they make it through to awk and don't get consumed by the shell.

```
awk 'BEGIN { INPUTFILE =\'XXX\'; iterator =0; ... '
```

All of your problems go away if you put the awk script into a separate file rather than inlining it the shell.  You can have whatever quotes you like and no one will care !!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if I put a double quotes instead of single or if I dun even put a quote

Comment: Your awk script has singles and doubles in it, so any quote you use will be "wrong" unless you escape them. I'll edit my answer with a bit more info...

Comment: At a quick glance, it seems that you could substitute double quotes for single quotes inside the script throughout.

Comment: I have cleared this error and now I am getting a single syntax error which I have shown by editing the question

Comment: Strip bits of it out to narrow down the error. to me this bit looks odd: if ($1 ~ /RequestId/)  -> should it be =~ (I'm more used to perl than awk these days...)

Comment: @John3136: no, in awk, you use `~` for regex matching.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. You learn something new everyday! - I'll leave the comment there though - the bit about stripping the problem down still stands.

Comment: Am I supposed to use a statement like this if((storageFlag =='T' && $0 != "EOE"))

Comment: I am not sure can anyone try to run this code in your machine . It will be a really helpful if I get the error

Comment: Finally I figured out :):):) .. The problem is a semicolon has to be inserted after the next